# Is it possible to make Blender prompt to save on exit?

Tags: customization

Does Blender have a setting or addon that makes it prompt you to 'save unsaved changes' when you close the window like other applications? I cannot count the number of times I have lost small pieces of my work because I exited the program just to check if I had made any changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.miikahweb.com/en/blender/svn-logs/commit/44925), (But only on MS-Windows) open *User Preferences* and look under *Interface*, you should see a checkbox with *Prompt Quit* beside it.

[image]

*Additionally, or preferably you can use* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> *to save it and make it load with your other defaults.*

**About Macs:**

Closing the app with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> invokes the save prompt. Quitting with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> doesn't. (possible bug?)
The only indication that you haven't saved is the 'dot' in the red, close-window  button, top left of the window.

[image]

Comment: To bad it doesn't work on linux..

Comment: @gandalf3 you have to use `Ctrl + Q`, updated my answer.

Comment: hm.. I know about Ctrl + Q, but never really used it..

Comment: On Mac, Cmd+Q does invoke the 'wanna save?' prompt. Cmd+W doesn't.

Comment: @MikePan thanks for clarifying this. Can you add it to the answer please.

Comment: Why not `Ctrl + Alt + U` to save user preferences only? `Ctrl + U` would also save everything else (e.g. scene objects) to startup file

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + U` does not *save* the user preferences, only opens the window. (you must still click "save user settings").  

I just tested the *Prompt Quit* setting, but it doesn't seem to do anything? clicking the "X" at the top of the window closes blender without any prompts.

Comment: @gandalf3 That's odd. You have to save once and have unsaved changes for it to prompt. This works for me on windows.

Answer (score 10):

Additionally, Blender auto saves to a temporary directory every 5 minutes by default,
(settings located in *User Preferences* > *File*)

It also automatically saves a `"quit.blend"` file in a temporary directory when it has exited. (This is recoverable by going to *Info* > *File* > *Recover last session*)

Blender even saves backup files in the directory that your file is saved in
(foo.blend1, blend2) for a more permanent backup.
See this question for more info on this.. [Blender saves a new file every time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/blender-saves-a-new-file-every-time)

All of this is default behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Also
 [image]

that star indicates unsaved changes.