# Window close button [x] ignores changes

Tags: edit-mode

I am kind of new to Blender and have only tried & used the video editor.

However, I am so surprised that Blender just quits when I click on the Windows close button (the [x] in the window decoration bar), despite changes have been made to the current blender working context.

Is it too difficult to have this checked and pop up a dialog with something like "All changes will be lost. Continue?  [Yes] [No]"?

Also, when Blender crashes, catching signals allows the software to at least try to make an emergency save of the current blender working context, which can be loaded next time.

These kind of actions are common in most software that I use on my Fedora Linux system. I'm surprised that a mature package as blender does not do this. Does it have a specific reason?

R.L.

Comment: possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-prompt-to-save-on-exit

Comment: I have a popup saying "Some changes have not been saved. Do you really want to quit?" on windows, but it looks like it's not in Linux systems (don't know why). Check this for auto save : http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14413/11431

Comment: Is too dificult use standard CTRL+S shortcut?  :-) I'm happy that Blender does't bother by useless dialogs :-)

Comment: @Shubol3D - I like that, too. It rarely happens that I loose something important in Blender, even if it crashes hard, because there's always at least one auto save.

Answer (score 2):

How to recover Lost work in Blender

1. Go to "File" -> "Recover autosave"
2. Use *.blend1 file - it is save before last save :-)
3. In splash screen use "Recover Last session" - open automatically saved project on Exit Blender.

Comment: Probably late for you, because the best is do this immediately after first Blender launch after crash, but can be helpful in future :-)