# Should I wait when Blender isn't responding?

Tags: performance

By error I placed the angle of the smart uv unwrap to 1 and now Blender is not responding. I guess it calculates the uv. The problem is that I have a lot of unsaved changes on the mesh.

Should I wait it to come back to life or is there no point? Are there any possible solutions to save my unsaved data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wait if you want, but it's probably going to take a long time before it will start responding. If you close it there is a way to recover you data; Blender autosaves your projects every 5 minutes, and you can change it if you want.

When you open Blender, go to 'File', then in the option, click 'Recover Auto save', wait for some time, and Blender will show all the autosaves it has taken according to the date. Click the unsaved projects, and save it when it opens.

Answer (score 5):

In cases like this, I always look at CPU, RAM and HDD usage. Also I take into consideration the last task which I gave Blender to do. This helps me decide what's better: terminate Blender or wait.

There are no right answers that work in every case. All depend on the particular situation. In your case: how fast is your CPU, how much memory you have and how many vertices your model has (consider also subdivision modifiers).

PS: Here you can find three ways for recover your work:

*[Window close button [x] ignores changes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/window-close-button-x-ignores-changes/62342#62342)*

Answer (score 4):

From experience, things like this (accidentally setting some setting to an insane value) will *usually* come back eventually, unless you run out of memory or blender crashes. Depending on what it is, on my machine these sorts of incidents are usually over within a few seconds, or perhaps a few minutes.

Only once or twice have I ended up giving up after letting it sit for a few hours.

However, you needn't wait around.
Open up a new instance of blender, click *File > Recover Auto Save...*, and try opening the most recent auto-saves (thumbnail view can be useful here). Chances are one of them is within a minute of the moment of disaster, and you can happily resume near where you left off.

See [How to setup Auto Save?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14413/599) for more detail on the auto save system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a very large project onto blender, it may be best to wait for your output.

For example, i loaded 53,000 chunks of a minecraft world into blender, waited, and got my country loaded block by block.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very particular situation. You gotta know what you did last and check the resource usage of blender.exe and see if the RAM getting higher slowly in small batches with CPU not that high. If it is, probably there some lazy-ass unoptimized script trying to calculate something not in the best way so you can wait in this kind of situations. But if your CPU and/or GPU all locked in high percentages you better unplug it right away because it's probably not worth it and you can go back and do it in a better way.
Like when you try to bool complex shapes with self enabled. It's like using 80s tech and almost like you can feel how script gets the vertices one by one and takes its time to calculate the new value. My setup is Ryzen9+RTX3060 but still having a lot of difficulties because of these neglected script pieces.