# How to make blender confirm closing an unsaved file?

Tags: blend-files, saving

I know that this question has already been asked here, but it was 5 years ago, and I want to know if the answer has changed.

Can I make blender confirm closing an unsaved file? (I am using ubuntu linux)

Thanks!

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-prompt-to-save-on-exit. Probably so far that dialog is still is built using system dialog window so works for Windows only. Try using Ctrl+Q for exiting instead (a workaround of course).

Answer (score 3):

Open *File > User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>), under *Interface* tab on the lower left *Prompt Quit*

[image]

Comment: I dont have this option. I am on linux.

Comment: You are probably using a very old version of Blender

Comment: 2.79b. Very new.