# How to disable the "Save Over" popup

Tags: customization, interface, shortcut

I'm accustomed to saving frequently using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Blender. Each time I do this, Blender pops up the "Save Over?" button, which I have to click (or press Enter).

This gets in the flow of things. Is there a *reasonably simple* method to disable this behavior and just Save Over without prompting. (Reasonably simple meaning without modifying Blender's source code.)

Comment: One of the more alien design choices in Blender! I wish we could disable it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this cannot be changed. Here are a few workarounds that might be helpful however.

### Use a script

If you use the command [`bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_2/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile) and register a shortcut, you would just need to do a normal save once *(for Blender to get the path)* and after that, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> as I have done in the script below to save without any popups. *(You can also change this if you want, see the commented line).*

```
import bpy

class SaveWithoutPrompt(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.save_without_prompt"
    bl_label = "Save without prompt"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SaveWithoutPrompt.bl_idname)

addon_kmaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SaveWithoutPrompt)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
    # change the shortcut here..
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(SaveWithoutPrompt.bl_idname, 'Y', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
    addon_kmaps.append(km)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SaveWithoutPrompt)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    for km in addon_kmaps:
        wm.keyconfigs.addon.kmaps.remove(km)
    del addon_kmaps[:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

### Set the autosave feature to save more often

[image]

You could have Blender save a copy of the file you are working on every minute. This runs in the background so no popups. You can find this feature under the *File* tab in your *User Preferences*.

Related, [Blender saves a new file every time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1212/12)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to overwrite the Ctrl+S shortcut with the script? (so Ctrl+S executes the script instead of the popup) you could probably also make the script call the file browser if the file has not yet been saved.

Comment: @gandalf3 It _is_ possible to overwrite `Ctrl + S` and yes, a first call to save could be done, I omitted that bit since I was in class at the time. Really trivial tho.

Answer (score 3):

**No**,
The way the save operator (`bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile`) works is when its activated with the filepath property set (as with `File -> Save`), it will execute immediately, but when its activated from a key-binding where the filepath is not set. it will activate a popup menu.

The only way around this is to create your own operator which calls `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile` with the filepath set. Then bind the key to this new operator.