# Disable save (Ctrl+S) confirmation possible?

Tags: customization, shortcut

Confirmation for *Save As* is logic but for *Save* is absurd. No other program that I use has this. How can I disable it?

Comment: I actually find this useful, as I don't have to worry about saving by mistake (maybe I'm testing something destructive such as applying a modifier or something and I don't want to worry about going past the undo limit. This actually has happened to me in programs like GIMP, but it's less of a problem in GIMP as it has infinite undo). The confirmation always appears right under the cursor, so it doesn't slow me down much (no need to aim the cursor before clicking). But to each their own, I suppose..

Comment: For me it's useless because I get used to click on it automaticaly and it doesn't prevent my "mistakes".I never need more than 3-5 undos. A helpful implementation will be delayed save with a custom interval(0-30sec.) and a button in the header for canceling.

Answer (score 4):

Although I wouldn't recommend this (I always increase the version number before saving), it is possible. Open up the *User Preferences* and add the parameter [check_existing](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_release/bpy.ops.wm.html) to the save function referenced from the dialog: (Note I tested this with <kbd>F2</kbd> you might prefer the other expanded dialog)

> check_existing (boolean, (optional)) – Check Existing, Check and warn
>   on overwriting existing files

[image]

Comment: You have a bunch of versions of each project? Doesn't that fill up your hard drive pretty fast? Why don't you use some sort of version control for that? http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/08/20/using-mercurial-version-control-with-blender-projects/

Comment: It works only for SaveAs file dialog but not for Save with Ctrl+S shortcut.

Comment: @Jusin Just to make sure that I can get back to a previous version, sometimes I mess things up and notice it hours later when the undo can't no longer help. I would use VCS if it were integrated to blender, I delete the intermediate result when I finished a model.

Comment: @user3444 Yes, the console prints search for unknown operator 'WM_OT_save_mainfile(check_existing=False)', 'wm.sav
e_mainfile(check_existing=False)' `I don't understand what makes the difference here

Comment: @stacker [How to disable the “Save Over” popup](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3016/3444)- the last answer here might give you some idea. Because of the formulation I didn't find it at first before I ask the question.

Comment: @user3444 Thanks, now I remember the thing. This also means that this question is a dup.