# Blender is saving as a blend1 file, not blend

Tags: export

I teach Blender to classes of game design students in the University of California and a student came to me yesterday with a problem I haven't seen before. She's created a very simple file, but when it's saved Blender puts a .blend1 extension on it every time, not the normal .blend. This means that after it's saved twice there are two .blend1 files in the directory, and no .blend file. I have no idea why this is happening. What has she done? Anyone seen this before?

thanks - Chris

Comment: Not that I can help you, but it might be helpful to know if the file names are absolutely identical (I'd be curious to know how that would be possible) or if Blender (or the OS for that matter) changes the name in some other way. And if she saves it yet another time, are there three .blend1 files, or two .blend1 and one .blend2?

Comment: They're identical. No, I have no idea how that's possible either. I thought I posted a screenshot, but for some reason it's not appearing. Anyway, the names are identical.

Comment: It would be interesting to take a look at User Prefs *File* tab regarding that feature setup, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/blender-saves-a-new-file-every-time. As it stands, it makes .blend1 to be .blend2, .blend to be .blend1, and then saves a blend. It could be a bug if it works partially..

Answer (score 15):

That's Blender's file versioning system. A very subtle but quite helpful feature. When you open the settings panel, under **File**, you can specify how many previous versions of a file you want to keep around on your computer.

So everytime you hit save, Blender maintains a stack of previous versions of the same file so you have some backup of your work and don't overwrite your progress when saving.

[image: Settings]

In the above screenshot, the last 5 versions of one `.blend` file are saved. All suffixed individually (`.blend1`, `.blend2` and so on).

You can enable showing file versions in the open file dialog if you want to pick a specific version from your save history (red arrow). And also you can toggle showing normal `.blend` files in that dialog (green arrow) which is what your student probably did.

[image: Open File Dialog]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, since the OP clearly states that there is no .blend file, but instead two .blend1 files.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley yes that was an accident, I fixed it!

Comment: Thanks - and I wasn't aware of the filter, useful - but her file consistently saves as a blend1 file. There are two blend1 files in the directory, which is crazy, but that's how it is.