# What is the Blend file (1) that is generated automatically?

Tags: blend-files

After I have been working on a project I notice that there is another file in the folder i.e. a blend1 file. This is the same size as the original blend file and doubles the amount of storage used.

Is it just a duplicate of the original file or does it contain different but essential information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender is saving as a blend1 file, not blend](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64334/blender-is-saving-as-a-blend1-file-not-blend)

Comment: That answers it, thank you. I did search before posting but didn't find this answer.