# Multiple versions of autosave files

Tags: customization

Very recently, blender crashed and deleted some of my work.  I looked into the autosave directory after I tried to reopen my file.  The reopened older version (without my recent changes) was the only version available in the autosave directory.  It disappointed me that my changes were gone in the very recently autosaved file.  In the user preferences panel I saw some autosave settings, none of which seemed to change how many previous versions of autosave files there were.

My question is this:
*Is there a setting in the user preferences that will alter the amount of autosave versions saved as seperate files?  Is there an addon that will work to the same effect?*

Cheers

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save. Autosave versions and their amount are setup in the User Preferences > File

Comment: @Mr Zak But the "save versions" value is for saving _manually_ (I know this setting deals with the blend1, blend2 etc. files), the true autosave settings only include frequency, not number of previous versions.

Comment: Save versions is something automatically saved in addition to the main saved file but this occurs [only in time of saving file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/blender-saves-a-new-file-every-time) with Ctrl+S.This is the amount which can be setup. [No way by default](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/recover.html#recovering-auto-saves) to enable autosaving mutliple versions of the file. Autosave depends on time period setup in the Timer below Auto Save Temporary files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an addon now. You can find it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/addonsByMe/master/auto_blend_save.py).

The *Save on open* option lets you go back to the start, while *Save before close* covers you for forgetting to save when opening another file or starting a new one, it doesn't get triggered before closing blender so that can still get you. While they do sound good, they can be a bit much if you just go quickly looking through a lot of blend files.

File copies are saved with a timestamp prefix in the name, so you can easily see how old any copy is or choose how far back you want to go.

[image: prefs for auto save addon]

Comment: Thank you! I installed the addon, still yet to use it in order to access Blender-crash-lost work in the future.